# Migration of TFS 2013 projects (Iterations and areas)

Tags: tfs, migration, mapping

I am using TFS Integration Platform to migrate projects/Work Items in the TFS 2013
http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

In project A (source project) I have defined a set of iterations and areas but they are not migrated to project B (destination project).

I have tried to copy the xml settings shown here:
http://www.vlaquest.com/2012/05/tfs-integration-tools-configuration-for-work-items/

into the XML that I am using but it has no effect. I don't understand how the mapping in the XML must be defined to match the project structure in TFS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own tool ([WitSync](https://github.com/giuliov/WitSync)) to understand what you need to migrate. I designed some mapping rules to manage Areas and Iterations as there are many scenarios to support.